# Querying inside a subdocument array in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Am really new to MongoDB or NoSQL database.
I have this `userSchema` schema

```js
const postSchema = {
    title: String,
    posted_on: Date
}

const userSchema = {
    name: String,
    posts: [postSchema]
}
```

I want to retrieve the posts by a user in given range(/api/users/:userId/posts?from=date&to=date&limit=limit) **using mongodb query**. In a relational database, we generally create two different sets of tables and query the second table(posts) using some condition and get the required result.
How can we achieve the same in mongodb? I have tried using `$elemMatch` by referring [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/) but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you add the query you are trying to do? 
Also `$elemMatch` will return a single array element that matches the condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 ways to do it with aggregation framework, that can do much more than a find can do.

With **find** we mostly select documents from a collection, or project to keep some fields from a document that is selected, but here you need only some members of an array, so aggregation is used.

**Local way** (solution at document level) no unwind etc

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZDyGSj3ylOd)

Query

- filter the array and keep only posted_on >1 and <4
  (i used numbers fro simplicity use dates its the same)
- take the first 2 elements of the array (limit 2)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "name": {
        "$eq": "n1"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "posts": {
        "$slice": [
          {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$posts",
              "cond": {
                "$and": [
                  {
                    "$gt": [
                      "$$this.posted_on",
                      1
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "$lt": [
                      "$$this.posted_on",
                      5
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          2
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Uwind solution** (solution at collection level)
(its smaller a bit, but keeping things local is better, but in your case it doesn't matter)

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/V-JyquuMIyi)

Query

- match user
- unwind the array, and make each member to be ROOT
- match the dates >1 <4
- limit 2

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "name": {
        "$eq": "n1"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$posts"
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$posts"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$and": [
        {
          "posted_on": {
            "$gt": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "posted_on": {
            "$lt": 5
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$limit": 2
  }
])
```